# Electron Issue about close.window() Method

Tags: window, electron

I have a Electron App which, on the press of a button, opens a new Window. Said Window has another button with the id of "closeBtn". Now i try to handle it in the js associated to said element with the following code

```
const electron = require("electron")
const path = require("path")
const remote = electron.remote

const closeBtn = document.getElementById("closeBtn")

closeBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
    window.close();
})
```

But somehow that doesn´t work, and the new window is not closing on the Button Press. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: It works here. Maybe try adding a log statement to see that you are getting a window ref: `   console.log('window', window);`

Comment: Thank you for your Reply. I fixed it by adding the webPreferences with the nodeIntegration property set on true to my created Window. After this the functionality is given as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by adding webPreferences {nodeIntegration: true} to the values of my newly generated Window.

Comment: Got the same issue. Can you explain a bit?